# Expression for number of items in a matrix with p% chance of having an item in each position

Tags: matrix, data-structures, statistics, probability, probability-theory

I'm working on a sparse matrix project for a programming course. To prove our project works, we are required to show that it can handle adding two 1000x1000 matrices together that fit the following criteria.

`Each element in each matrix has a 5% chance of being a 1, otherwise it is a 0.`

My current method to construct one of these matrices is shown in the following pseudocode:

```
p = .05
loop M from 0 to 1000 {
    loop N from 0 to 1000 {
        diceRoll = generate random number between 0. and 1.
        if (diceRoll < p){
            Matrix[M][N] = 1
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that I could go about this in a more efficient way by determining how many 1's should be in the matrix, and then randomly placing them throughout. eg. a 1000x1000 matrix should have roughly 5% of its spaces with ones, which means 1,000,000 * .05 = 50,000 ones.

However, the first method does not always yield a matrix with exactly 5% one's; note that it could in theory yield a matrix full of zero's, or a matrix full of one's.

How can I make an expression to determine (or approximate) the number of one's to put in a matrix, given the dimensions and `p` ?

Comment: 5% chance should indeed mean a probability rather than an observed frequency. So, having not exactly 5% of ones should be fine. Next, deviations from 50000 are unlikely to be large. E.g., it looks like a deviation larger than 2000 has probability lower than 0.0007. So, as for your last sentence, if you know that each entry is 0 or 1 independently and with the same probability, there is nothing you can do to "decrease" their number; that would be fighting randomness.

Comment: @JuliusVainora how did you determine that _deviation larger than 2000 has probability lower than 0.0007_ ? Thanks!

Comment: Using Hoeffding's inequality. Also, the total number of ones should be well approximated by the normal distribution with mean np and variance np(1-p); the 95th percentile of it is 50358.5.